# How efficient is concurrent network requests on iOS or Android?

Tags: android, ios, networking, afnetworking, okhttp

First, please let me know if I should separate this question into one for iOS and one for Android. But I am working on both and was curious about this in a bigger picture sense, so thought I would ask this way. Here's the question:

Unlike on desktop, normally on mobile apps we try to minimize the number of network requests, and in my case I've been only making a single network request per view until now. But I have started wondering how performant it would be to make multiple concurrent network requests to different API endpoints simultaneously and then use those.

The reason I've started thinking about this approach is because I'm fetching a lot of data for the app, and wanted to split them up so that they can be maintained separately. I know web browsers do it (since that's how browsers work), but I was curious if anyone has experience building mobile apps this way.

Basically, whenever a view loads I would like to make multiple requests to different API endpoints (between 2 to 4) and use the combined result as I receive the result back from all of them, instead of a single huge result from a single endpoint.

Would this be performant enough? I'm using AFNetworking on iOS and OKHTTP on Android, if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Suppose the overhead in bytes of each HTTP request is 100 bytes. This is a rough approximation; in practice the overhead varies with the HTTP headers (including cookies or authentication credentials), the URL (long query strings and paths aren’t free), the HTTP version (HTTP/2 has compressed headers) and other factors.

If you split a 1 MiB response into four 256 KiB responses, the 100-bytes-per-response overhead is completely negligible. It’s 0.03% more data.

But if you split a 100 byte response into four 25 byte responses, the per-overhead impact is dramatic. You’ll be transmitting 150% more data.